# Render a template file from module's controller method

Tags: theming, 8

I wanted to create and render a custom twig template, like it is described at Drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2640110. I have a module which is called "game" and has this route in the **game.routing.yml** file:

```
game.index:
  path: '/gamecanvas'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\game\Controller\MainController::gameShowCanvas'
    _title: 'Gamecanvas'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

The route works with the controller below - I have tested it with different output. The controller is located at **game/src/Controller/MainController.php** and looks like this:

```
namespace Drupal\game\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class MainController extends ControllerBase {

  public function gameShowCanvas() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'game',
      '#description' => 'foo',
      '#attributes' => [],
    ];
  }

}
```

The **game.module** file looks like this:

```
function game_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'gamecanvas' => [
      'variables' => []
    ]
  );
}
```

The **game.html.twig** file in **game/templates folder** contains just the word "hello", to indicate that the template file content output works.

If I call http://my-website/gamecanvas, I do not see the desired output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys. I needed to change the value of "#theme" into "gamecanvas".

Drupal 8 is excepting NAME.**html**.twig. NAME.**tpl**.twig does not work. Mind the "html" in the file name.

The working code looks like the following.

MainController.php:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\game\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Default controller for the permissions_by_term module.
 */
class MainController extends ControllerBase {

  public function gameShowCanvas() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'gamecanvas',
      '#description' => 'foo',
      '#attributes' => [],
    ];
  }

}
```

game.module:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function game_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'gamecanvas' => [
      'variables' => []
    ]
  );
}
```

gamecanvas.html.twig:

```
hello
```

game.routing.yml:

```
game.index:
  path: '/gamecanvas'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\game\Controller\MainController::gameShowCanvas'
    _title: 'Gamecanvas'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your template to `gamecanvas.html.twig` and adjust your controller-code:

```
namespace Drupal\game\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class MainController extends ControllerBase {

  public function gameShowCanvas() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'gamecanvas',
      '#description' => 'foo',
      '#attributes' => [],
    ];
  }

}
```

Your theme-key is `gamecanvas` but you are referring in your controller to `game`. You should also add `description` and `attributes` to your theme-declaration, as they get stripped out by drupal otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The main error in the code you are showing is the incoherence between the theme hook you define, and the one the controller is using.

Either you edit `game_theme()`, or you edit `MainController::gameShowCanvas()`. In the first case, the code should be the following one.

```
function game_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'game' => ['variables' => []]
  ];
}
```

Also, since you are using `#description` and `#attributes`, it is probable you need to use the following code.

```
function game_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'game' => [
      'variables' => [
        'description' => 'default value for description',
        'attributes' => 'default value for attributes',
      ],
    ]
  ];
}
```

Differently, Drupal would not use `#description` nor `#attributes`.

Also, as general rule, a module with a machine name like game should not define a routing for /gamecanvas, since this could conflict with a module using gamecanvas as machine name. Take as example the Node module; it has a route for /node/{node} not /node_menus/{node}.